# Middleware implementation not working for some routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes, backend, middleware

In my project, I have 2 different functions serving as middleware, which are in a separate file in a separate directory, and I have imported them in my route files.
However, one of the functions executes properly while the other throws and error

The first middleware function (which is functioning properly) is :-

```
isLoggedIn : function(req,res,next){
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
            return next();
        }
        res.redirect("/login");
    },
```

The other function (not working) is :-

```
checkCampgroundOwnership : function(req,res,next){
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
                Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err,foundCamp){
                    if(err){
                        res.redirect("back");
                    }
                    else{
                        if(foundCamp.author.id.equals(req.user._id)){
                            return next();
                        }
                        else{
                            res.redirect("back");
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            else{
                res.redirect("back");
            }
        }
```

I'm implementing them in my routes as follows :-

```
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
    req.body.description = req.sanitize(req.body.description);
    Campground.create(req.body.camp, function(err,created){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            created.author.id = req.user.id;
            created.author.username = req.user.username;
            created.save();
            res.redirect("/campgrounds");
        }
    })
})

router.put("/:id", middleware.checkCampgroundOwenership, function(req,res){
    Campground.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.camp, function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            res.redirect("/campgrounds/"+ req.params.id);
        }
    })
})
```

The error which is generated is as follows :-

> Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object
>   Undefined]

What is the problem and how to solve it

Comment: Which line is this error related to? Are you able to call the first route correctly?

Comment: Yes the first route is functioning properly. It is the second route (PUT route) that is giving the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

You've typed: `checkCampgroundOwenership`

Should be: `checkCampgroundOwnership`

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your `isLoggedIn` and `checkCampgroundOwnership` as follow:

```
exports.isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
   //your code...
};
```

So you can import in your routes file.